# I need a Boundary Value Problem to test for the wikipedia table of Green's functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

I just want a *specific* example (preferably in 2-D) of a PDE (preferably steady-state) that I can test which can be solved using one of the Green's functions from [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Table_of_Green%27s_functions). I'm mostly asking as a sanity check, because whenever I try to set up my own problem and test the Green's functions from the table by computing the solution, they don't end up working for me, usually because the RHS of the PDE when plugged in does not allow the integral to converge.

A specific example would look something like: $$\Delta u(x,y) = -2\Big(x(1-x)+y(1-y)\Big); \ \ 0 < x,y < 1 \\ \cases{u(0,y) = 0, \\ u(1,y) = 0, \\ u(x,0) = 0 \\ u(x,1) = 0}$$

Any example will do, I just want one that can use Green's function from the table. Thank you!

Comment: The Green's function must also satisfy the boundary conditions.

Comment: @Gonçalo I'm not asking for a critique of the example I provided if that's what you're getting at. That was simply to serve as a template for what I'd like it to look like when I say "specific" as in don't give something like $Lu = f(x)$ and have that be it.

Comment: That's a surprisingly bad Wikipedia article; it does not, for example, discuss the question of convergence/representability of solutions by the Green's function for the stuff listed in the table. A lot of those examples have large kernels of solutions to the homogeneous equation, some not so easy to even characterize. If you want an actual answer, take a function which is smooth enough and has compact support (say $u = (1 - |x|^2)^2_+$), compute the Laplacian directly (easy enough), then use the Green's function for the Laplace operator listed there to recover $u$.

Comment: @user378654 For the example you provided, I just wanted to know if the green's function for the 2D Laplacian Operator would work since u is in 1-D? I mean I suppose it might, we would just plug in 0 for y and it's corresponding dummy variable, right? Thanks!

Comment: I meant $x$ as a vector, so $|x|^2 = x_1^2 +\ldots + x_n^2$; this works in any dimension, the key point is that the function is actually compactly supported this way. Using just $x_1^2$ "works" in 2D, but not for obvious reasons and you'll have convergence issues with the integral.

Comment: @user378654 so for the solution $u (x,y) = ((1-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2))^2$, I have it plotted and I can see the solution is 0 where $G(x,y) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \ln(x^2+y^2)$ is also 0 along the boundary $-1\le x,y \le 1$. It looks like they satisfy the same Boundary conditions along the same finite boundary. Should the integral instead be $\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 f(x,y) G(x,y,\xi,\eta) d\xi d\eta$ to be within the boundaries? Or would it still be infinite domains of integration? And thanks for the help! I also have had issues with the wiki page's examples as introductory material.